Find a function $\delta$ such that $(3x^3+x) \delta(x)^2 \rightarrow \infty$ and $(9x^3+x) \cdot \delta(x)^3 \rightarrow 0$

Let $f(x) := 3x^3+x$ and $g(x) := 9x^3+x$. Find a function $\delta$ such that $f(x) \cdot \delta(x)^2 \rightarrow  \infty$  and $g(x) \cdot \delta(x)^3 \rightarrow  0$ for $x \rightarrow \infty$.

I can see that the condition $g(x) \cdot \delta(x) \rightarrow  0$ requires $\delta = \mathcal{o}(x^{-1/3})$, but I can not see how to connect this with the other condition, $f(x) \cdot \delta(x)^2 \rightarrow  \infty$. Could you please help me?

I am fairly sure that I have seen an almost identical question today – here it is: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4923822/42969

Yeah its the same question word-for-word.

Consider
$$\delta(x)=\frac1{x^{4/3}}$$
Edit
Search $\delta(x)$ in the form $\delta(x)=\frac1{x^a}$, then you must have:
$$f(x)(\delta(x))^2=\frac{3x^3+x}{x^{2a}}\to \infty \quad \text{if} \quad 3>2a\\
g(x)(\delta(x))^3=\frac{9x^3+x}{x^{3a}}\to 0 \quad \text{if}\quad 3<3a
 $$
So you can choose $a$ such that $a\in]1,3/2[$.
